# Verifying Identification Results for Univariate Regression

Tags: regression, linear, matrix, univariate, identifiability

So I have this linear regression model shown below and I'm supposed to be showing that equation 3 is equal to equation 4. There's a hint that says a 2x2 inverse matrix appears in the proof, but the inverse of xx' doesn't exist (?)

Am I supposed to be rewriting beta in matrix terms? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first step, we will rewrite the Equation 3 more explicitly. The first term $E[X'X]$ can be rewritten as:

**Note:** The random vector $X$ is composed of a constant value of 1 due to interception and a random term $X_1$. Since this is the only random variable in the vector, I will use $X$ instead of it.

\begin{equation*}
  E[X'X]^{-1}=E\left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & X \\
X & X^2
\end{bmatrix}\right\}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & E[X] \\
E[X] & E[X^2]
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\[2em]=
\frac{1}{E[X^2]-E[X]^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
E[X^2] & -E[X] \\
-E[X] & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\[2em]=\frac{1}{Var(X)}
\begin{bmatrix}
E[X^2] & -E[X] \\
-E[X] & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then, the second term $E[XY]$ can be written as:

\begin{equation*}
E[XY]=
E\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
X 
\end{bmatrix}Y\right\}=\begin{bmatrix}
E[Y] \\
E[XY] 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Now, we can substitute these matrices into Equation 3. With some algebra, we can easily reach Equation 4.

\begin{equation*}
\beta=E[X'X]^{-1}E[XY]= \frac{1}{Var(X)}
\begin{bmatrix}
E[X^2] & -E[X] \\
-E[X] & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
E[Y] \\
E[XY] 
\end{bmatrix}\\[2em]=\frac{1}{Var(X)}\begin{bmatrix}
E[X^2]E[Y]-E[X]E[X,Y] \\
E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] 
\end{bmatrix}\\[2em]=\frac{1}{Var(X)}\begin{bmatrix}
E[X^2]E[Y]-E[Y]E[X]^2+E[Y]E[X]^2-E[X]E[X,Y] \\
Cov(X,Y) 
\end{bmatrix}\\[2em]=\frac{1}{Var(X)}\begin{bmatrix}
E[Y]Var(X)-E[Y]Cov(X,Y) \\
Cov(X,Y) 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
E[Y]-E[X]\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} \\
\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\beta_1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the quick reply. I really appreciate it. I was just stuck at finding the inverse properly, so I couldn't progress any further. I understand your working. Thanks a lot!